# How to return unique values from list of pairs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of pairs given as:

```
a = [[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
```

I would like to return unique matches as a new list for all numbers inside 'a'. As an example, I'd like to create something like below - i.e. where I can select any number from 'a' and see all other numbers associated with it from all of the pairs. The list of lists, b, below is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
b = [ [0,[1]] , [1,[0,2,3]] , [2,[1]] , [3,[1]] ]
```

I am open to more efficient/better ways of displaying this. The example above is just one way that came to mind.

Comment: not related to question: why are you using python 2? If it's an option, or if you're just starting, please consider using python 3. Is there some reason why you have to use python 2?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Share your attempts

Comment: Hint: create a `defaultdict` of `set`s.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I don't have a choice, as my work only has Python 2 installed unfortunately

Comment: @AlexandreB. I was trying to solve via a for loop, but it became ugly so it was not worth including here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if your list contains lists with different length:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
b = defaultdict(set)
for items in a:
    for item in items:
        b[item] |= set(items) ^ {item}
```

To get exact output you ask for use:

```
c = [[key, list(value)] for key, value in b.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is even better :)

Comment: @Jwem93, do you need any explanation?

Comment: If that is okay, I would love to understand this better. It works just as I'd hoped however I haven't seen notation like '| =' and am not sure what {} or set does?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
c = defaultdict(set) # default dicts let you manipulate keys as if they already exist
for item in [[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 1]]:
    # using sets avoids duplicates easily
    c[item[0]].update([item[1]])
    c[item[1]].update([item[0]])
# turn the sets into lists
b = [[item[0], list(item[1])] for item in c.items()]
```